# Can I install Couchbase within a virtual environment?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, virtualenv, couchbase

I'm trying to use Couchbase with a Python program I wrote. I'm on a Mac. This doesn't really matter but I'm working in PyCharm. I create a virtual environment in terminal and put Python there and then have PyCharm use the Python in my virtual environment. Now I want to install Couchbase for the first time.

I don't even know how to use Couchbase yet, although I can see, from the Couchbase reading I just started doing, that it would be easy to use if I just did the normal download onto my Mac. But can I avoid the standard download/installation of Couchbase and just do everything from my virtual environment, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it via docker https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/server/builds.

I personally like to install it via Kitematic